# City labels visibiliity different in device and Google Maps APIs Styling Wizard

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using [Google Maps APIs Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) to define a custom map styling in my android app. The problem is that the wizard shows the city labels very clearly:

[image]

whereas my android device (and emulator) does not:

[image]

The labels appear on the device as I zoom in but I need at least the big cities to be visible from the original zoomed out view.

I tried enlarge the screen, just to ensure there is enough space for the labels and I tried almost every possible combination of settings in the wizard but I cannot find the answer.

Here is my style.json

```html
[
  {
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#616161"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.country",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      {
        "weight": 8
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.country",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#000000"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.country",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.country",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "lightness": 5
      },
      {
        "weight": 7.5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#bdbdbd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "weight": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#a0a0a9"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "on"
      },
      {
        "weight": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#94959e"
      },
      {
        "weight": 8
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#94959e"
      },
      {
        "lightness": -35
      },
      {
        "weight": 8
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9898a8"
      },
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      },
      {
        "weight": 8
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dde0e5"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#eeeeee"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#757575"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#dadada"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#e7dcb9"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#7db0f1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "color": "#9e9e9e"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```